# iOS：How can I make a double variable change from 0.0 to 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, animation

As described in the title, I wanted to change a double variable (a property of the class) from to 0.0 to 1.0. Because I wanted achieve an animation effect with the [DACircularProgressView](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress), and I wrote the code for it:

```
func showProgressView() {
    progressView = DACircularProgressView(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60, 20, 40, 40))
    if let progressView = progressView {
        progressView.progress = 0
        addSubview(progressView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { 
            progressView.progress = 1
            }, completion: { (finish: Bool) in

        })
    }
}
```

First I think the `animate` can make a variable gradually increase as the `alpha` property. As a result, I can't get it. So, seek help.

Thx.

Comment: Use a NSTimer and increase the progress value between 0 to 1 incrementally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate a custom property in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540897/how-to-animate-a-custom-property-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong. You can't animate the changing of a variable. What you should do is use the `setProgress:animated:` method provided by `DACircularProgressView`.

```
func showProgressView() {
    progressView = DACircularProgressView(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60, 20, 40, 40))
    if let progressView = progressView {
        progressView.progress = 0
        addSubview(progressView)
        progressView.setProgress(1, animated:true)
    }
}
```

FYI - I'm not a Swift expert so the syntax might not be perfect for the call to `setProgress`.

Comment: Thanks. I suddenly found that I am so silly.... > < #. And can I control the animation time?

Comment: I found the `indeterminateDuration` function. Thx again~ ^_^

Comment: @Desgard_Duan Glad I could help. Please don't forget to close your question by accepting the answer.

Comment: Anyone searching for an answer to the title [see how to animate variable QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545451/8740349)